# Microsoft CRM - Querying through Entities with Form Scripting

Tags: javascript, crm

I am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM and I got a question.

I have an entity Constituents and Service Request. For each service request, there is a corresponding Constituent. Now, in the Constituent entity, there is a field "Receive Text Notification". Every time the status of a Service Request is changed, I would like to send a SMS message to the regarding Constituent.

My function for sending SMS is working properly. I only like to know how could I get the value of the field "Receive Text Notification" from the Constituent entity. I am using Javascript for the form events.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show some code ;)

Comment: i still got no code for i really have no clue on how to get it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, you are writing JavaScript on one entity and you wish to retrieve data from another related entity.

Best way to do that is with REST calls, which I blogged about here: [Getting started with CRM 2011 JavaScript REST (OData) Web Service Calls](http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/getting-started-with-crm-2011-javascript-rest-odata-web-service-calls/).